# ACF group field disappeared after deployment using deployer script

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, deployment

When I deployed a code from local to staging server after ACF Fields are disappeared in the pages, I am using a deployer script to deploy a code from the local environment to a staging environment also I have checked ACF JSON folder permission so that permission is 755 and also I have tried with 777 but still the same issue facing.

If anyone facing the same issue and found a solution please share the answer in the comment.

Comment: Have you synced the ACF Fields? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/local-json/#syncing-changes

Comment: Yes fields are already synced but after deployment, I need to save them manually after fields are visible on the page, but that process is annoying because there is lots of fields so if i do save manually so too much taken time.

Comment: So is there any way to update all the field groups on the single group update fields or something other solution? actually, I want to keep fields on the pages without doing any saving fields group process.